# NSDateFormatter - set device language as locale?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, localization, nsdateformatter, setlocale

I'm trying to get the iPhone to display dates formatted by an `NSDateFormatter` in the current device language.

I have tried `setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]`, but that only returns `5` instead of `May` (or `Mai`, as I want it to be).

**EDIT**: `currentLocale` shows `May` (english). `systemLocale` shows 5 (I think systemLocale is Norwegian), and `autoupdatingCurrentLocale` shows `May` as well.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks! :)

NEVERMIND - The simulator played a trick with me, it works on a real device. #

Comment: There are a few other class methods like `+systemLocale` and `+autoupdatingCurrentLocale`. Have you tried these?

Comment: At StackOverflow, if you have solved your own problem, you should post your solution below instead of editing the question. After a while, you will be able to accept your own solution, which marks the question as "answered", so this means you don't need to append `[resolved]` to the question title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had forgotten to set the Region Format to my local region format :)

Comment: QA filed a bug on my app because they had forgotten to do that, and then I forgot to do it and could reproduce the bug…

Comment: thanks, yes, this is the correct answer, I see many answers use the" [df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]]];" to set the locale, i thing it is wrong, we should use setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale], then switch both the language and region format to the proper values, everything works fine..